# Trying to log in to MyFitnessPal via requests: what am I missing?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to access my account on MyFitnessPal in order to download my own food diaries. However, whenever I run the following code, I am consistently redirected to the login page. What am I missing? In the HTML code for the login page, I only see two input tags, one for "email" and one for "password", both of which I'm making sure to supply. I'm pretty new to web scraping, so any advice would be appreciated!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Save relevant urls
base_url = 'https://www.myfitnesspal.com'
login_action = '/account/login'
login_url = base_url + login_action

date = datetime.datetime(2022,3,13)
fmt_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
food_url = base_url + '/reports/printable_diary/?from=' + fmt_date + '&to=' + fmt_date

headers = {'user-agent': {user agent}}
credentials = {'email': {email}, 'password': {password}}

s = requests.session()
login = s.post(login_url, headers = headers, data = credentials}
r = s.get(food_url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

What ends up getting printed is the HTML from the login page. (I have confirmed this by also printing the login page's HTML.)

Comment: when I run this page without JavaScript then it send login as GET, not POST

Comment: when I run this page with JavaScirp then it send login as POST but to `https://www.myfitnesspal.com/api/auth/callback/credentials?` and it sends also many other values - like `csrfToken` which is `hidden` in `form`

Comment: it is better when script behave like real human - so first GET login page to get cookies. And you need it also to get hidden values in `form`

Comment: it seems it gets `csrfToken` from https://www.myfitnesspal.com/api/auth/csrf - so code has do the same.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful. So to clarify, I should 1) GET login page and then 2) GET the /api/auth/csrf page & search the content to get hidden values in form?

Comment: yes, 1) create `Session()`, 2) GET login page to get fresh cookies and maybe to get some hidden values in `form`, 3) POST  `/api/auth/csrf`  to get `csrfToken` (it may need header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'` to simulate AJAX request), 4) POST all data to `/api/auth/callback/credentials`. You can use `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab: `Network`) to see all requests send from browser to server when you login in browser. And then you should see details for your requests. Video example for [DevTools](https://youtu.be/TOQz_W2oELU) in `Firefox` but for different page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: r = requests.get('https://www.myfitnesspal.com/account/login', auth= ('email', 'password'))

I got a 200 response wit this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).